# How to handle reference or pointer type in swig

Tags: java, c++, swig

Need a small favor.
Actually i have a large cpp project for which i am writing swig wrapper to be called from java.
Please suggest best approach to do this using swig.
Though i am working on it and facing one issue:
Actually i have some method declarations similar to below one:

```
static int& GetValues(const int* id, User& userDetails);
```

I have written interface file for the same and getting below generated java classes along with other classes:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_userdata__User.java
SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_int.java
SWIGTYPE_p_int.java
```

So please help me out to get rid of this type of class generation.

Note: I have included below interface files from swig itself:

```
%include <stdint.i>
%include <windows.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%include "std_string.i"
%include <swiginterface.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The answer depends on what the function in question does with the parameters. Are they input/output/both? The `SWIGTYPE_p_` types are required so the generated SWIG wrapper can handle type recognition and conversions between the two languages and will always be there unless you define your own [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps) for them. I'll be able to help with a more definitive and descriptive answer later when I have bit more free time on my hands :)

Comment: Hi @Pesho_T, Thanks a lot for your time. Actually parameters will be used for both input and output. My actual problem here is that how will i use SWIGTYPE_p_userdata__User.java, SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_int.java, SWIGTYPE_p_int.java classes in my java code. As java does not support pointer or reference type so how does swig help here to access those type of objects or variables. Sorry if issue is still not described properly. I will try to post a demo code for the same. Thanks again.